# Include User-Agent info in a nginx access log bash script

Tags: bash, logging, nginx, awk

I've got a working bash script that tells me nginx access logs as they come in, formatting the raw logs into colorful pieces of information.

Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure how to take what I've already created, and add in showing the User-Agent of the request. I want to be able to look at a glance which User-Agent was used. Was it Googlebot? Was it Firefox 22 on Windows?

Here's the bash script I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_DEFAULT_PATH="/var/log/nginx/access.log"
LOG_PATH="$1"

if [ "$LOG_PATH" = "" ] && test -f "$LOG_DEFAULT_PATH"; then

  echo -e "\033[35mAuto-detected Log File: \033[32m$LOG_DEFAULT_PATH\033[0m"
  LOG_PATH="$LOG_DEFAULT_PATH"

fi

if [ "$LOG_PATH" = "" ]; then

  echo -e "\033[32mUsage: $0 /path/to/nginx/access_log\033[0m"

else

  (tail -n 500 -F $LOG_PATH | awk '{printf "%s%s %s %s%s%s %s %s %s%s%s %s%s\n", "\033[40;1;35m", $5, $6, "\033[0;32m", $1, "\033[37m", $10, substr($7, 2), "\033[31m", $8, "\033[36m", $2, "\033[0m"}')

fi
```

The body of the script is in the line that begins with the tail command. I'm using awk to print the different pieces of the request into the terminal, and color each piece. It is here that I would assume the User-Agent information would also be shown.

Here's the log format:

```
  log_format  vhost_combined  '$http_host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
                              '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                              '"$http_user_agent"';
```

Of course, any suggestions on better scripting would also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should notice that awk using " " as default to split fields. However, inside the field, like $time_local or $http_user_agent, there are blanks, thus the fields split may quite different than you thought. Using regex in awk to split log could be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question sometime ago but forgot to update here.

The following is the script I came up with:

```
#!/bin/sh

LOG_DEFAULT_PATH="/var/log/nginx/access.log"
LOG_PATH="$1"

if [ "$LOG_PATH" = "" ] && [ -f "$LOG_DEFAULT_PATH" ]; then

  echo -e "\033[35mAuto-detected Log File: \033[32m$LOG_DEFAULT_PATH\033[0m"
  LOG_PATH="$LOG_DEFAULT_PATH"

fi

if [ "$LOG_PATH" = "" ]; then

  echo -e "\033[32mUsage: $0 /path/to/nginx/access_log\033[0m"

else

  sudo tail -n 500 ./nginx-access.log | perl -n -e'/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"$/ && print "\033[40;1;35m[$5 $6]\033[0;32m $1 \033[37m$11 $8 \033[31m$9 \033[36m$2 \033[30;1m$14\033[0m\n"'

fi
```

Essentially, the main part or bulk of the scsript is the `perl` command at the bottom. It separates out the log format using regular expression and then displays some of the variables using `print`.

The user-agent is displayed last in bold gray text using `$14` from the regular expression.

Further explanation can be given if desired by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, pay attention to the blank space inside the field, because awk using    space as default separator, you may not get the correct fields as you want. You can using -F option to change the default separator, or you can use regex in awk to do this. An example for regex in awk:

```
awk '{if(match($0,/GET ([^ ]*)/,a)){print a[1];}}' access_log
```

And a regex you could refer looks like this:

```
^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) \[([^\]]*)\] \"([A-Z]+) ([^\"]+)\" (\d+) (\d+) \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" ([\d\.]+)( (\d+) (\d+))?
```

The result:
[image]

If could not see the picture clearly, right click it and reopen in another tab to see the original size.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I've tried multiple ways. I did get the first example pattern to work, though. What would the command-line option be for the answer?

Comment: Try to understand how it works and modify it according to your case. You want to get the User-Agent from the log, right? Read the manual, use 'man awk or awk --help' to see how to use a custom field-separator. Try google 'awk match' and find how it works, trey to modify the regex and make it suitable for your case, but you'd better not ask for the code directly, try to understand it.